# Json parse date time format

Tags: c#, json

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to parse json objects but one object that have date and time in it wont be parsed as it's stated.

```
JObject a = JObject.Parse(response);
```

a will get the whole json and last is the object i want.

,  "last_activity_date": "2017-03-29T18:05:38.707Z"}

```
var date = a["last_activity_date"];
```

will output

```
date = 2017-03-29 18:05:38
```

Is it possible to keep the date time as it is? 2017-03-29T18:05:38.707Z
Or do i need to use regex?

Comment: Maybe I don't know as much about datetime as I thought.. but is The "Z" at the end legit?

Comment: The Z at the end signifies UTC

Comment: Also known as 'Zulu Time'.  https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to default `JObject` parsing configuration, your `last_activity_date` will be treated as `Date` type, if you want to treat it as a string, you'll need to create dedicated class and deserialize your JSON into object.

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("last_activity_date")]
    public string LastActivityDate { get; set; }
}
```

You can use `JsonConvert`:

```
var obj = (Root)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Root));
Console.WriteLine(obj.LastActivityDate); //outputs: 2017-03-29T18:05:38.707Z
```